# Importing modules from separate paths in Python

Tags: python, import

I'm trying to import modules from separate paths but the error it's returning is "module not found." It's importing modules from the directory the script is executed in but will not change directories and import from said directory.

```
print(os.getcwd())
```

When I run this, before it throws the error it couldn't find the module, it will output the parent directory so for example I'll go with **test\import\modules**.

I'll run a script in **\import\** to import test_0.pyd from **\import\** and test_1.pyd from **\modules** (test.py and test_0 being located in **\import\** and test_1 being located in **\modules**. Also, I have tried relative importing and every directory contains ****init**.py**).

```
import test_0 # this would work
from modules import test_1 # throws error that module isn't found
```

So I run the print command and it returns that it's trying to import from **test\** and I've tried changing directories but it'll say the working directory changed when I print, but still outputs that it couldn't find the module. Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you.

**EDIT**
http://prntscr.com/6ch7fq - executing test.py
http://prntscr.com/6ch80q - import directory

Comment: You can add paths with modules as follows `sys.path.append('../import')` for example.

Comment: I've tried that too but it still throws the "module not found" error.

Comment: so please, clarify your project structure. Its not clear from the question where is what, and how you call your program.

Comment: main.py is supposed to import both files but won't change directories to modules which has the test_1.pyd file to import it. Sorry if this is confusing, I really do not know how else to put this

Comment: You can also use relative imports, e.g. `import ..forder1.foder2.mymodule` which translates to `../folder1/folder2/mymodule.py`

Comment: I've also tried that but it still returns that it couldn't get the module. Would a prntscr screenshot help?

Comment: Any additional info/screenshot would be useful. The best would be minimal working example, that we can actually recreate. Otherwise, as you see, this is more of a  guessing game.

Comment: I've edited with screenshots, I tried to fit one more in but http://prntscr.com/6ch84t it's just the folder that contains test_1 pyd

Comment: Please show your `test.py` and whats inside modules folder.

Comment: for test.py `from test_0 import ExecFTPDL
from modules import test_1` and for the modules folder the screenshot in my last comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you start python from a directory, that directory is added to your `PYTHONPATH` so modules are importable from that directory and below, provided you've got an `__init__.py` in each directory, including the top level that you're running python from. See here:

`~/Development/imports $ tree
.
├── __init__.py
├── mod1
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── a.py
├── mod2
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── b.py
├── top.py`

So when we start python from `~/Development/imports/`,  we can access `top` `mod1.a` and `mod2.b`:

```
~/Development/imports $ python
Python 2.7.8 (default, Nov  3 2014, 11:21:48)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.54)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import top
>>> import mod1.a
>>> import mod2.b
>>> import sys
```

But when we start python from inside `mod1`, we're not allowed to go outside of `mod1` back to `top` or to `mod2`:

```
~/Development/imports/mod1 $ python
Python 2.7.8 (default, Nov  3 2014, 11:21:48)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.54)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import a
>>> from .. import top
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package
>>> from ..mod2 import b
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package
```

Relative imports `from ..mod2 import b` only work from a module below the top level module that you started from, because they are all implicitly in the python path.

You can't escape *outside* of the module you start from unless that particular path is added to `PYTHONPATH` or `sys.path`:

```
~/Development/imports/mod1 $ PYTHONPATH=../ python
Python 2.7.8 (default, Nov  3 2014, 11:21:48)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.54)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import a
>>> import top
>>> import top.mod2.b
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named mod2.b
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path.append('~/Development/imports/mod2/')
>>> from mod2 import b
>>>
```

So, you need to ensure that all of your directories have an `__init__.py` file in them. You also need to ensure that you're starting python from the right location, usually the top directory. You can't start python half way down the directory structure and expect to get back up to the top, or sideways to another directory/module.

Comment: that's what it was wow. I moved it up to the root changed the import lines and it worked simple fix for such a buggy problem haha thanks for this you explained it well I'll accept as soon as I can!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have `__init__.py` file in the said modules/directory? This is required for python to treat it as a package.

Check out [What is __init__.py for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448271/what-is-init-py-for)

Comment: yes, I edited the post shortly before you said this but I checked everything and I'm currently getting screenshots which I'll post then

Comment: @Norghar your screenshot shows that the directory **does not** have an `__init__.py` file in it.

Comment: it did but it was hidden I forgot to uncheck that, sorry